# How to populate user avatar image in App Maker project?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-app-maker, google-directory-api

In the top right of every sample App Maker project, they have this:

[image: Top right of App Header Bar]

It's fairly easy to bind the email string to `@user.email`, but how would one go about populating the avatar image? Do I need access to the Directory API and/or Google Cloud SQL, just for this functionality? I'm not currently using either of those things in this project.

Thanks!

Comment: Normally you need to use the Directory API. For all of my projects the image is bound to datasources.Directory.item.ThumbnailPhotoUrl

Comment: I'll give that a shot. Do you then replace the default "label" that comes with their sample code with an image?

Comment: I thought that most of their samples had both an image and a label widget and they set the image visibility to visible if there is a ThumbnalPhotoUrl and the label to invisible.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: I never did, sorry @PremierBromanov